# Distraction Free Mode with right margin

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-14

I'd like to display right margin in Distraction Free Mode. Is it possible? Can't find any options for DFM in settings.

Right margin is the vertical line displayed in a tab with source code. It shows where the column limit is.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open the settings and navigate to Editor > General > Appearance and tick "Show hard wrap guide (configured in Code Style Options)".

Alternatively bring up the Find Action search with Ctrl+Shift+A (by default), search for "Show right margin" and hit enter to toggle the setting.

The trick is to change it *with distraction free mode enabled*.

**EDIT**: In versions of IntellJ before 2017.3, the menu option was called "Show right margin".

Comment: Very useful, thank you. I thought it was not possible.

Comment: This got me hopeful that I could also turn on line numbers, when in distraction free mode, but that does not seem possible. At least I have the right-margin bar now.

Comment: @Kevin: you can turn on line numbers in the same way. With distraction free mode enabled go Settings > Editor > General > Appearance and tick "Show line numbers".

Comment: @tmccarthy, thanks for the reply, but I did try that. The numbers come on until the next time I interact with with the editor. (I do use the Vim plugin, maybe there is bug there.)

Comment: An easy way to show line numbers is by right clicking to the right of the code and selecting "show line numbers" in the dialog.

Comment: This is no longer working for me in IntelliJ 2017.3. That right margin option is gone, and turning on the replacement 'visual guides' while in distraction free mode doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @stkent It looks like the option has been renamed to "Show hard wrap guide". I've updated my answer above accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this, now I wish this same _with distraction free mode enabled_ trick applied to "Highlight modified lines in the gutter"…